# Examples of Forcing in Model Theory

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, forcing

My question is exactly my title: What are some examples of (set theoretic) forcing in model theory?

I have been studying (combinatorial) set theory and model theory (independently of one another) for some time now, and I want to know how the former can be applied to the latter. The wikipedia page on [forcing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_%28mathematics%29) states: "Forcing has also been used in model theory but it is common in model theory to define genericity directly without mention of forcing". I have, regrettably, never encountered this scenario and would like a *concrete example*.

Ideally, any non-trivial application of forcing to model theory would be nice.

Thanks

Comment: I asked my model theory professor about that once. He didn't have an example either. Reverse mathematics uses forcing to some extent, but I wouldn't call it model theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I used to talk to a computability theorist a lot and he said the same thing. There has to be some results!

Comment: I think that in Chicago you should be able to get quicker answers by knocking on some office doors. Of course it's winter break now, so it's probably not that good of advice for right now.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I am meeting with Malliaris after break; maybe she has something to say about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably take a look at the classification theory text by Shelah. There area lot of results there are based on additional cardinal hypothesis, and combinatorial principles and has (set-theoretic) forcing in the background to establish relative consistency. There are places where you use forcing to establish the result also (however I can't think of a exact reference expect to say it comes up in the study of models of size $\aleph_{1}$ that are atomic but not prime) These types of results also appear in works about AECs (abstratct elementary classes).

I'm however a little confused by the article though. There is a notion of forcing based on the same ideas that is used in model theory that is called model theoretic forcing and I think that this what the article is referring to. It is due to Abraham Robinson. A good place to get details about this would be the book "Building models by Games" by W.Hodges.

EDIT: You also asked how to apply combinatorial set theory to model theory. For example most of the arguments in classification theory use a lot of set theoretic combinatorics, for example the proof that unstable theories have $2^{\kappa}$ models for any uncountable $\kappa$ comes to mind.

Comment: I think you might be missing the point. The question is about using forcing (approximation with a partial order, and generic filters) to generate new models of theories which are not set theories.

Comment: @Asaf  And model theoretic forcing does that. For example the  omitting types theorem can be seen as a model theoretic forcing argument.

Comment: I was talking about the first paragraph, which refers to set theoretic assumptions.

Comment: @Asaf I'm not entirely sure. He did say applications of set theoretic forcing to model theory and then again he asks how to apply combinatorial set theory to model theory. For example most of the arguments in classification theory use a lot of set theoretic combinatorics, for example the proof that unstable theories have $2^{\kappa}$ models for any uncountable $\kappa$ comes to mind.

Comment: Well, I felt that the first part was an introduction to the question about forcing over general models. But let's wait for Kyle to wake up and find this present under his Christmas tree. See if he likes it. :-)

Comment: @DanulG: While I think your response is in some sense correct, I am looking for something with more meat. I would like to see a result (and maybe a proof, or a link to a proof) where one actually uses forcing to show the independence of some model theoretic principal. Something where forcing is directly applied model theory. I know Baldwin's book demonstrates some proofs under VWCH (the Very Weak Continuum Hypothesis) as well, but I would like to see a forcing poset which interacts with model theory (if that is even possible).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: ^